# Dropdown menu not staying open long enough to click

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdown

I've been trying to work this out all day -- I'm working on an ecommerce based on Woocommerce and so having a mega menu is desirable. Usually, when I start a new project, I have a barebones version of the theme as a starting point. I have implemented a mega menu (with walker) on this barebones theme and it works fine.

When I hover over the trigger, the menu should show and the user can then click the links in the dropdown menu.

For some reason, the dropdown in the 'real' version of the site doesn't work. The dropdown shows, but as soon as you try to move the mouse to a link, it disappears.

The website can be seen on a demo URL here: http://demo.imaginaire.co.uk/covercraft/

Would massively appreciate some help as I feel like I'm banging my head against a wall! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is about 15 pixels or so of space between the hover trigger (.dropdown-toggle) and the actual menu. That means that when you move your mouse to get it inside the menu, it hovers out of the dropdown toggle element for just a second as it passes over that 15 pixel space.

The solution to this depends on a few things, namely if you're using a theme you can edit directly (or need to make a child theme), or if you can edit the HTML structure a bit. However, just to demonstrate a VERY quick solution, you could probably just add this to your stylesheet:

```
.yamm .dropdown.yamm-fw .dropdown-menu{top:40px;}
```

This has the net effect of moving that dropdown menu up to be flush with the bottom of the dropdown-toggle, so you can demo it and see that it now works. However, this likely isn't the best solution to the problem and we'd probably need a little more info to give you a specific fix.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for that -- a fresh pair of eyes has highlighted a really obvious issue! I think it's probably the navbar padding causing the issue and so I'll work through a solution based on that. It's a custom theme we're developing so luckily we have a good amount of control over the styling. Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: Thanks! Happy to help -- And believe me, I know how you can stare at a problem for hours only to suddenly realize the issue within seconds the next time you take a look at it. :)